# Se puede escuchar un puerto serial (COM) si ya está en uso con otra aplicación? C#

Tags: puertos

Resulta que tengo un dispositivo que se conecta a una aplicación por puerto Serial, y almacena en la base de datos. Lo que necesito es también acceder a la información por medio de otra aplicación, algo así como un escuchador para realizar unas tareas lo mas tiempo real posible.

Intente con un código de la Documentación de Microsoft pero me sale error y creo que es porque el puerto ya está abierto, sin embargo si no lo abro y solo escucho no hace nada.

Muchas gracias.